# Xcode 8 : Build app with iOS 9 Base SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios10, xcode8

I have Xcode 8 latest (NOT BETA) , in order to compile my app with iOS 9 SDK . I copied the 9.3 SDK to /Applications/Xcode 8.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/ SDKs and modified Info.plist with MinimumSDKVersion to 9.0

Still i couldn't find the iOS 9 SDK in Base SDK selection. Could someone help on this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer these.

[Xcode 8 with older Base SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838406/xcode-8-with-older-base-sdk)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/43381

Comment: Tried the same but no luck so far.