# How to test Apple apps on upgraded iOS's

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, upgrade, xcode-ui-testing

I have built some UITesting Xcode automation suites.  I wanted to run these as part of iOS upgrade regression.

However, in order to test my suite on iOS 10, I needed to upgrade my Xcode from 7 to 8 and rebuild the app.  However, the app (IPA file) I have in live is built against iOS 7, therefore I am not really testing a true representation of live.

**In summary, I am testing an Xcode 8 IPA file against iOS 10, but I want to test an Xcode 7 IPA file against iOS 10 (to get a true representation of the live environ).**

Anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way we have gotten round this is to run UITesting in Xcode 8, but with the 'Base SDK' set to iOS 9.

Setting the Base SDK as iOS 9 in Xcode 8 is not as easy as selecting a value.  Here are full instructions:
[Xcode 8 with older Base SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838406/xcode-8-with-older-base-sdk)

Comment: This answer sounds like a guess. Does it fix it or not?