# Xcode8: base sdk not listing installed sdk

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode8

I have upgraded to Xcode8 but need an older sdk(10.10) for some projects.

I have copied MacOSX10.10.sdk from an older xcode to the same directory containing MacOSX10.12.sdk.   However, when trying to select the base sdk, I am only give the choice of MacOSX10.12.sdk.

Pics below showing my sdk directory and the options xcode is giving me.

I have also tried 'Other' and changed the 12 to 10, but the sdk was not found.

Why am I not given the option to select MacOSX10.10sdk?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One must edit an info.plist to specify a minimum sdk.

See the link below for more details.

[Xcode 8 with older Base SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838406/xcode-8-with-older-base-sdk?rq=1)