# Build w/ iOS 9.x SDK, debug on ios 10.x device?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have an app which, due to some serious compatibility issues, I'm still building with the iOS 9.x SDK. Making modifications to get it to compile with the 10.x SDK would be a large undertaking. So, I've just been using Xcode 7.

The problem is that because of this, I can't effectively debug on iOS 10.x devices, as (of course) XCode 7 doesn't recognize iOS 10 devices.

Is there any way to get the best of both worlds? E.g. run XCode 8, debug on iOS 10.x devices, but build using the iOS 9.x SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838406/xcode-8-with-older-base-sdk) which does the trick. I successfully used this method, built using the iOS 9 SDK using XCode 8, and the resulting binary was accepted into the App Store. One small note, I had to use Application Loader to upload the binary to iTunes Connect, as I was getting unexplained errors when trying to upload directly from the XCode Organizer. Not sure whether that had anything to do with the older SDK, but just in case, figured I'd mention it.