# XCode 9: Build iOS app for iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode

With the latest changes on iOS 11, when I updated my iOS game and exported the ipa file for BaseSDK iOS 11 and arm64, armv7, armv7s, the Unity game is no longer working on the 32bit devices running iOS 9.

Is there any way to target iOS SDK 9.x.x to enable my game to run on iphone 5 and the non 64 bit generation iPads ?

My game is live in the store and many players with 32 bit devices complain it stopped working and it closes when they open it.
[image]

Comment: Check out thisI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838406/xcode-8-with-older-base-sdk

Comment: I saw it but in info.plst I don't have MinimumSDKVersion setting..

Comment: @DeyanVitanov You don't set it manually in Info.plist. Select your project and look for "iOS Deployment Setting" on the Info tab.

Comment: Thank you guys. I manage to compile it at the end but it is still crashing on iOS 9 and 32 bit devices. I have feeling I'm missing something?